# nested owl carousel 2 not working

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

I have 2 owl carousel nested [like](https://jsfiddle.net/ugrw2vjq/3/)

 This is html structure

```
    <li class="product">
        <ul class="product-image-slider owl-carousel">
            <li>image 1</li>
            <li>image 1</li>
        </ul>
        content here..
    </li>
    <li class="product">
        <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>1</li>
        </ul>
        content here..
    </li>
    <li class="product">
        <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>1</li>
        </ul>
        content here..
    </li>  
</ul>
```

and this is js script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            var outerCarousel = $('.product-lists.owl-carousel');
            outerCarousel.owlCarousel({
                loop: true,
                center: true,
                items: 1,
                nav: false,
                dots: false
            });

            var innerCarousel = $('.product-image-slider.owl-carousel');
            innerCarousel.owlCarousel({
                loop: true,
                center: true,
                items: 1,
                nav: false,
                dots: false,
                /* mouseDrag: false,
                touchDrag: false,
                pullDrag: false */
            });

        });
```

But when i drag carousel inner (product-image-slider) then parent carousel also drag.
I try to disable or prevent parent carousel but not working. Like

```
innerCarousel.on('drag.owl.carousel', function(event) {
        outerCarousel.data('owl.carousel').settings.touchDrag = false;
        outerCarousel.data('owl.carousel').settings.mouseDrag = false;
    });
    innerCarousel.on('dragged.owl.carousel', function(event) {
        outerCarousel.data('owl.carousel').settings.touchDrag = true;
        outerCarousel.data('owl.carousel').settings.mouseDrag = true;
    });
```

How can i do it thank

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this out

https://jsfiddle.net/ugrw2vjq/19/

insted of using `drag.owl.carouse` and `dragged.owl.carousel` events 
you can use the mousedown core event of owl carousel.

to achieve what you want, you have to stop the propagation of this event from the inner carousel to the outer carouse, so the mousedown event will fire on the inner carousel but would not be propagated to elements behind id.

(you can aslo add the touchstart event as I did in my example if your carousel should work with touch)

do you need your carousel to be on loop? as you put the inner carousel in the first slide and that slide is clonned when on loop it will cause you issues when dragging the main carousel from the first element backwards

Comment: Thankiu your help, second issues is that you talking about. Loop not working in outer or inner carousel. do you have any idea? thank

Comment: this one is harder, owl-carousel, create clones of the slides in order to achieve the loop effect, when you are instanciating both players at the same time, the cloned element inside `product-lists` dont exist yet and carousels are not created for them, even if you fix that then the cloned carousel has to be in sync with the original one, my advice is avoid looping, or don't place item that have carousel in the first or last position